# onelogin SSO shibboleth ACS config

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, shibboleth, onelogin

I am trying to get Shibboleth SP to work with OneLogin [SAML Test Connector (IdP w/attr)] in my lab. I was able to get everything working with testshib IDP but when I change out my Metadata provider and update my SSO Entity ID I just get this error:

SAML message delivered with POST to incorrect server URL

When looking at my metadata file I see that my ACS is:

http://testserver/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

but when this is placed in my OneLogin test connector all I get is the above error.

Below is my Shibboleth2.xml file (with entity ID's removed)

```
    <SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" clockSkew="1800">
<!--  Windows RequestMapper  -->
<!--
 The RequestMap defines portions of the webspace to protect; testserver/secure here. 
-->
<!--
 https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPRequestMap 
-->

    <InProcess logger="native.logger">
        <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="false">
            <!--
            Maps IIS Instance ID values to the host scheme/name/port. The name is
            required so that the proper <Host> in the request map above is found without
            having to cover every possible DNS/IP combination the user might enter.
            -->
            <Site id="1" name="testserver"/>
            <!--
            When the port and scheme are omitted, the HTTP request's port and scheme are used.
            If these are wrong because of virtualization, they can be explicitly set here to
            ensure proper redirect generation.
            -->
            <!--
            <Site id="42" name="virtual.example.org" scheme="https" port="443"/>
            -->
        </ISAPI>
    </InProcess>

<RequestMapper type="Native">
<RequestMap applicationId="default">
<Host name="testserver">
<Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>
</Host>
</RequestMap>
</RequestMapper>
<!--
 The entityID is the name TestShib made for your SP. 
-->
<ApplicationDefaults entityID="" REMOTE_USER="eppn">
<!--
 You should use secure cookies if at all possible.  See cookieProps in this Wiki article. 
-->
<!--
 https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPSessions 
-->
<Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" checkAddress="false" relayState="ss:mem" handlerSSL="false">
<!--
 Triggers a login request directly to the TestShib IdP. 
-->
<!--
 https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPServiceSSO 
-->
<SSO entityID="">SAML2</SSO>
<!--  SAML and local-only logout.  -->
<!--
 https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPServiceLogout 
-->
<Logout>SAML2 Local</Logout>
<!--

                Handlers allow you to interact with the SP and gather more information.  Try them out!
                Attribute values received by the SP through SAML will be visible at:
                http://sdserver/Shibboleth.sso/Session

-->
<!--
 Extension service that generates "approximate" metadata based on SP configuration. 
-->

<Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata" signing="false"/>
<!--  Status reporting service.  -->
<Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="127.0.0.1 ::1"/>
<!--  Session diagnostic service.  -->
<Handler type="Session" Location="/Session" showAttributeValues="true"/>
<!--  JSON feed of discovery information.  -->
<Handler type="DiscoveryFeed" Location="/DiscoFeed"/>

</Sessions>
<!--
 Error pages to display to yourself if something goes horribly wrong. 
-->
<Errors supportContact="root@localhost" logoLocation="/shibboleth-sp/logo.jpg" styleSheet="/shibboleth-sp/main.css"/>
<!--
 Loads and trusts a metadata file that describes only the Testshib IdP and how to communicate with it. 
-->
<MetadataProvider type="XML" file="onelogin_metadata.xml"/>
<!--
 Attribute and trust options you shouldn't need to change. 
-->
<AttributeExtractor type="XML" validate="true" path="attribute-map.xml"/>
<AttributeResolver type="Query" subjectMatch="true"/>
<AttributeFilter type="XML" validate="true" path="attribute-policy.xml"/>
<!--
 Your SP generated these credentials.  They're used to talk to IdP's. 
-->
<CredentialResolver type="File" key="sp-key.pem" certificate="sp-cert.pem"/>
</ApplicationDefaults>
<!--
 Security policies you shouldn't change unless you know what you're doing. 
-->
<SecurityPolicyProvider type="XML" validate="true" path="security-policy.xml"/>
<!--
 Low-level configuration about protocols and bindings available for use. 
-->
<ProtocolProvider type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="protocols.xml"/>
</SPConfig>
```

Metadata (again sensitive information removed)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/">
  <IDPSSODescriptor xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/"/>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/"/>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/soap/sso/"/>
  </IDPSSODescriptor>
  <ContactPerson contactType="technical">
    <SurName>Support</SurName>
    <EmailAddress>support@onelogin.com</EmailAddress>
  </ContactPerson>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

The connector only has these settings:

ACS (Consumer) URL Validator:
^http://testserver/shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST$

ACS (Consumer) URL
http://testserver/shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

Comment: Can you share SP metadata and what you set at the connector?

Answer (score 1):

This [guide](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector) explains to you how configure the OneLogin's connector.

- Audience: http://testserver/shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
- Recipient: ->IdP Entity ID<-
- ACS (Consumer) URL Validator: ^http://testserver/shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST$
- ACS (Consumer) URL: http://testserver/shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

At Shibboleth:

Edit */etc/shibboleth/shibboleth2.xml* to add the metadata url as a metadata provider.

I saw you already got the metadata URL for the app by logging into OneLogin as admin and clicking onTest Connector > SSO tab > Issuer URL.

and added it to the file:

```
<MetadataProvider type="XML" file="onelogin_metadata.xml"/>
```

Add attribute mapping, Edit */etc/shibboleth/attribute-map.xml* and add the following attributes:

```
<!-- OneLogin attributes -->

<Attribute name="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" id="login">
 <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="ScopedAttributeDecoder"/>
</Attribute>

<Attribute name="User.Email" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" id="email">
 <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="ScopedAttributeDecoder"/>
</Attribute>

<Attribute name="User.FirstName" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" id="firstName">
 <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="StringAttributeDecoder"/>
</Attribute>

<Attribute name="User.LastName" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" id="lastName">
 <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="StringAttributeDecoder"/>
</Attribute>
```

The error that you experienced "SAML message delivered with POST to incorrect server URL" [is documented](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPTroubleshootingCommonErrors#NativeSPTroubleshootingCommonErrors-SAMLmessagedeliveredwithPOSTtoincorrectserverURL.):

```
When a SAML message is addressed to a location inconsistent with where the SP believes it's running, this error will be thrown. The SP pulls much of this information from the web environment.

* Verify that the server name and port are properly set in accordance with the SP's metadata.
* Rewriting rules in effect for the Shibboleth.sso handler path must be consistent with the SP's metadata.
* The IdP needs to properly address the SAML response.
```

Record the SAML flow with the [SAML Tracer Tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) and verify that a SAMLResponse is sent using the HTTP-POST binding to the http://testserver/shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST endpoint.

I'm not a shibboleth expert, but maybe is related to the fact of sending from HTTPS to HTTP as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shibboleth-users/YCJ6Zx5HiLE), explanation [here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPNoSSL)

Comment: Hello smartin. I had tried the SAML wiki but no luck. I tried the SAML tracer tool and I do see SAML going both ways but on the return it is red. I bumped back to TestShib and everything worked correctly (Green on both ways.) I then verified that TestShib is using the same ACS that I was and they are. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong still.